# How do I seperate this data frame that contains the names of 4 species, into 4 data frames that contain only one species each?

Tags: r, dataframe, parsing

I need to separate this data so that I can then make graphs (ggplot), and overlay them for a project I am working on but am struggling on separating the big data frame into 4 smaller data.frames based off of species name! Thanks!

Ive used the split function but it doesn't achieve the end goal that I am going for.

```
# A tibble: 230 x 18
   `Bee ID` Species Site    Treatment Wax   WaxTime Egg    EggTime Survival
      <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>   <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>   
 1      264 lucorum Heather Control   wax        13 NA          21 survived
 2      267 lucorum Heather Control   nowax      29 NA          25 survived
 3      291 lucorum Heather Control   wax         9 noeggs      29 survived
 4      312 lucorum Heather Control   nowax      29 noeggs      29 survived
 5      315 lucorum Heather Control   nowax      29 NA          16 survived
 6      324 lucorum Heather Control   wax         9 noeggs      29 survived
 7      327 lucorum Heather Control   nowax      29 eggs        26 survived
 8      330 lucorum Heather Control   nowax      29 eggs        24 survived
 9      390 lucorum Heather Control   nowax      29 noeggs      29 died    
10      393 lucorum Heather Control   nowax      29 eggs        11 survived
```

Comment: What is your expected output? And I only see one species name. How can you divide it into four?

Comment: You have *used the split function but it doesn't achieve the end goal*. What is that end goal? By the problem description it seems that that's exactly what `split` is meant for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it has been said in the comments, you haven't given us a ton of information. But, I think I know what you are looking for. I don't know what your other species are called, so I have a few placeholders `Species2`, `Species3`, and `Species4`. You need to fill these will your species names.

Lets call your data frame `data` for ease, but this will have to be replaced by whatever you have called your data.

```
Lucorum_data <- data[data$Species=="lucorum",]
Species2_data <- data[data$Species=="Species2",]
Species3_data <- data[data$Species=="Species3",]
Species4_data <- data[data$Species=="Species4",]
```

This code will grab all rows where Species=="yourspeciesname", and assign it to a new object which I have called "yourspeciesname_data".